# What's the difference between ledmon and ledctl?

Tags: drivers, storage, utilities

Both are LED control tools released by Intel.

https://linux.die.net/man/8/ledmon

https://linux.die.net/man/8/ledctl

What's their difference?

Do I need ledmon to be executed first to run ledctl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Ledmon can be run as a daemon to constantly monitor the status of
> drives and Software RAID and set the drive LEDs appropriately.
>
> Ledctl
> can be used to identify an individual drive on a backplane, useful
> when determining which drive maps to which drive bay slot.

https://www.dell.com/support/article/tw/zh/twdhs1/sln310523/using-ledmon-ledctl-utilities-on-linux-to-manage-backplane-leds-for-pcie-ssd-software-raid-drives?lang=en